# Custom columns in list view in Symfony admin generator

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

#### *tl;dr:* I need to show data from two different tables in the list view of the Symfony admin generator (preferably via a JOIN statement)

I'm using the `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` to manage the users of my app.  Each user also has their own profile that they can fill out.  The schema (`schema.yml`) for the profile table looks like this:

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    sf_guard_user_id: integer(8)
    client_id: string(128)
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local: sf_guard_user_id
      foreign: id
      foreignType: one
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

Right now table is a client_id and a foreign key to the id column on the sfGuardUser table.
*(Yes, I know I need an id column in there just for DB accessibility, and more is coming later)*

I've created an admin for my profile table using the Symfony admin generator.  I would like my list view on the admin to look like this (`generator.yml`):

```
config:
  ...
  list:
    title:   Clients
    display: [client_id, sf_guard_user_id, username]
    table_method: retrieveProfileList
```

However, my username column does not work, and I receive a `Doctrine_Record_UnkownPropertyException` of:

```
Unknown record property / related component "username" on "sfGuardUserProfile"
```

I was hoping a custom table_method to populate the data for the list view would help me, but my table method (in `lib/model/sfGuardUserProfileTable.class.php`) does not seem to help.  I followed an example in the [Symfony Book](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_table_method), and this is the method:

```
public static function retrieveProfileList(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
  $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();

  $q->leftJoin($rootAlias . '.sfGuardUser id');

  return $q;
}
```

Any ideas on how to have the Symfony admin generator display a list view based on a join?  Or, alternatively, how to pull from a separate model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered my own question!

I changed the join method on my `sfGuardUserProfileTable` class to something I could better understand (thanks to [this](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/) helpful link):

```
public static function retrieveProfileList(Doctrine_Query $q)
{
  return $q->select('r.*, u.username')
          ->leftJoin('r.sfGuardUser u');
}
```

And threw in a `getUsername` method in my `sfGuardUserProfile` model class

```
  public function getUsername()
  {
      return $this->sfGuardUser->username;
  }
```

Thanks for being my rubber duck, SO!